# Send camera video from an adobe air app to another

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

Using Adobe Air, I want to use a cellphone camera to capture video, and stream that video to another cellphone. I want to do a live streaming, and both phones will be on the same Wi-Fi netowork.

I know this can be done using a Flash Media Sever in the middle, but that precisely what i want to avoid. All i need is a two-way communication between two apps in two phones.

An idea, would be to use a socket connection between the two apps, and send each video frame as a byte array. But, maybe there is a better way.

Could i use a NetConnection and a NetStream?

Has someone done this before?

Thank you for any help you can bring.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use netconnection and netstream objects on both device. You will need a streaming server in the middle.

wowza, flash media server, or red5

If you use socket connection you might want to try native environment. With Adobe Air you can connect to the streaming server with Netconnection and publish with Netstream and/or playback the stream.

Let me know if you have any questions.